# Ubuntu host is unable to lock screen if a VM (virt-viewer/KVM) has input focus

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, lock-screen, virt-manager

I run Ubuntu 16.04 and some QEmu/KVM virtual machines with `virt-manager`.

Whenever one of my VMs has input focus and I leave my computer alone for enough time to trigger the host's automatic screen locking, nothing happens. I still see the VM window and the other Ubuntu windows, desktop etc and can continue working with the VM. Only when I release the VM's input focus again, the lock screen that should have been activated earlier kicks in and locks me out.

Why is this and how can I change this behaviour so that my host locks the screen normally, whether a VM is focused or not?